# tensorflowのGPU使用制限の設定について

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

GPUがひとつだけ存在するマシンでtensorflowを動かすとき、

```
gpuConfig = tf.ConfigProto(
    gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.5),
    device_count={'GPU': 0})

with tf.Session(config=gpuConfig) as sess:
```

と設定を行うと、nvidia-smiコマンドでGPU使用の詳細を調べたところ、freeなメモリが1GiB以上あるにもかかわらず、GPU memory usageの部分にそのプログラムが使用するメモリが25MiB程度しか取れていないと表示されてしまいます。
この問題はどう解決すればいいのでしょうか？どなたかご教授いただけると助かります。

Answer (score 1):

device_countは計算に使用するデバイスの数を指定するのでこの場合は1を設定するのが正しいと思います。
また使用するデバイスの数を制限するためのものなのでGPUひとつのマシンでGPUをひとつ使いたいのであればそもそも設定する必要はないでしょう。

以下に詳しい解説があります。
http://qiita.com/kikusumk3/items/907565559739376076b9

Comment: device_countを指定しないで実行した場合、　`I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:700] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 637.26MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:702] Stats: 
Limit:                   668215541
InUse:                   668215296
MaxInUse:                668215296
NumAllocs:                     247
MaxAllocSize:            258920448`のように表示され、OOMエラーが出てしまいました。これは根本的にメモリが足りないということでしょうか？

Comment: 根本的の意味によります。GPUを有効にした上で計算を何もしなければTensorFlowが確保するGPUメモリは100MB前後です。それ以上のメモリ使用量はモデルの大きさとミニバッチサイズに依存します。エラーの内容は試しているモデルとミニバッチサイズがGPUのメモリ容量を超えたという解釈になります。